# How to put data in a io.Writer into a io.Reader

Tags: go, io

I use a library that finally results in the output of this library in an `io.Writer` is written.
Now more I have data on this `io.Writer` to another library I have to pass that library just `io.Reader` accepts.
What should I do? Is there a way to copy a writer to reader?

```
// i have a writer and i'll give it to the library 
_ = png.Econde(writer,img)
// Now I need to pass it to another library as a reader 
_ = myLibrary.Read(??)
```

Comment: In general you can do that with a pipe, but before you complicate things, do check what your `writer` is. E.g. if it is a `bytes.Buffer`, it already is an `io.Reader`, so you can use it both as an `io.Writer` and `io.Reader`. Same goes for `os.File`: it implements both `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`.